# How to calculate the width if i am having bold text in MFC

Tags: mfc

This is sample code to calculate the width in normal text(with out bold).
--Now i want to calculate the Bold Text width.
I am having "Intermediatery bank:" as bold text

Can any one help ...please

```
int CPrintableInvoice::GetFormattedStringWidth(const CString& txt)
{
  if (txt.IsEmpty())
      return 0;

  CFont *pOldF, *pF = GetFont();
  CClientDC dc(this);
  pOldF = dc.SelectObject(pF);
  CRect r;
  dc.DrawText(txt, &r, DT_SINGLELINE|DT_CALCRECT);
  int wid = r.Width();
  dc.SelectObject(pOldF);
  return wid;
}
```

Thanks in Advance..

Thanks,
Hareesh.

Comment: To get the width of bold text requires you to create a font with the bold attribute and select it into the device context before performing the same calculation.  To create a bold font:  
1. Call `pF->GetObject(...)` to return you the `LOGFONT` structure.  2. Increase the `lfWeight` member.  
3. Create a new font using `CFont::CreateFontIndirect(...)`.  
4. Select it into the `CClientDC` and off you go.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GetTextExtent()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7e878zz.aspx) instead. It would go as follows:

```
CFont *pOldF, *pF = GetFont();
CClientDC dc(this);
pOldF = dc.SelectObject(pF);
CSize size = dc.GetTextExtent();
return size.cx;
```